# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'userCredentails.user')

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am building a user Authentication page for my react native app. Issues I can't update the displayName while signing up my user. After that I need to store the name, email,password in my Firestore database.

I am using expo and firebase. I can't understand why it is not working.

```
import firebase from "firebase";
import { auth } from "../../firebase";

const SignUpScreen = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  // const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

  // Sign Up ----------
  const handleSignUp = () => {
    auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((userCredentials) => {
        if (userCredentials) {
          const user = userCredentials.user;
          user.updateProfile({
            displayName: name,
          });
        }
      })
      .then((userCredentials) => {
        const user = userCredentials.user;
        // console.log("Registered with:", user.email);
      })
      .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `then()` block doesn't seem to be returning anything. Also `updateProfile()` function returns a promise. Try refactoring the code in async-await syntax as shown below:

```
const handleSignUp = async () => {
  try {
    const userCredential = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    const user = userCredential.user
  
    await user.updateProfile({ displayName: name })
  
    console.log("Registered with:", user.email);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

Comment: Though it didn't show any error the displayName was not updated.

Comment: @BISHALSAHA how are you logging the updated name? Can you share the updated code ?

Comment: I just console log the user object. Everything like the email, display name, photo, phone everything included in the user object. I tried your way but it didn’t work but no errors

Comment: @BISHALSAHA can you try `console.log(auth.currentUser)` right after updateProfile? Does that contain updated name?